# While using simplify feature slider does not appear using QGIS

Tags: qgis, simplify

Using QGIS both 1.8.0 and 1.7.4, the slider does not show up after selecting features and click "simplify feature" botton.

Is there any special setting needed to show the slider?

Answer (score 1):

The process for using the 'simplify features' button is to click the 'simplify features' button *then* click the feature you want to simplify.

See the bottom of page 69 in the 1.7 user guide

http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.7.0_user_guide_en.pdf

The user guide for that section is a bit confusing and probably the source of the problem.